# Why elements after restoration loses their offset between each other?

Tags: javascript, html, clone

I am trying to implement bookmarks thing for my site and testing this:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>test bookmark</title>
        <script type='text/javascript' src='libs/bookmarks.js'></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <input type = "text" id = "txt_id" />
        <input type = "button" value = "create bk" onclick = "createBookmark();" />
        <input type = "button" value = "restore bk 0" onclick = "restoreBookmarkNumber(0);" />
    </body>
</html>
```

bookmarks.js:

```
function Bookmark(of_elem, name)
{
    this.name = name;
    this.of_elem = of_elem;    
    this.elems = new Array();

    for (var i = 0; i < of_elem.children.length; i++)
        this.elems.push(of_elem.children[i].cloneNode(true));

    return this;
};

Bookmark.prototype.restore = function ()
{
    while (this.of_elem.hasChildNodes())
        this.of_elem.removeChild(this.of_elem.lastChild);

    for (var i = 0; i < this.elems.length; i++)
        this.of_elem.appendChild(this.elems[i].cloneNode(true));
};

var bookmarks = new Array();

function createBookmark()
{
    var name = prompt("Enter bookmark name", "Bookmark " + bookmarks.length);
    var bk = new Bookmark(document.body, name);
    bookmarks.push(bk);
}

function restoreBookmarkNumber(num)
{
    var bk = bookmarks[num];

    if (bk)
        bk.restore();
}
```

For some weird reason, the space between textbox and buttons disappears after bookmark restoration, but I don't understand why this happens. I clearly clone all elements, so what else it need?[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the places you're using `children` rather than `childNodes` (such as the `Bookmark` constructor), you're only dealing with **element** children (since that's the point of `children` vs. `childNodes`). Use `childNodes` throughout to ensure you maintain text nodes between elements, since text nodes between elements can be significant (e.g., for spacing).

Your original, which loses the spacing:

```js
function Bookmark(of_elem, name)
{
  this.name = name;
  this.of_elem = of_elem;    
  this.elems = new Array();

  for (var i = 0; i < of_elem.children.length; i++)
    this.elems.push(of_elem.children[i].cloneNode(true));

  return this;
};

Bookmark.prototype.restore = function ()
{
  while (this.of_elem.hasChildNodes())
    this.of_elem.removeChild(this.of_elem.lastChild);

  for (var i = 0; i < this.elems.length; i++)
    this.of_elem.appendChild(this.elems[i].cloneNode(true));
};

var bookmarks = new Array();

function createBookmark()
{
  var name = prompt("Enter bookmark name", "Bookmark " + bookmarks.length);
  var bk = new Bookmark(document.body, name);
  bookmarks.push(bk);
}

function restoreBookmarkNumber(num)
{
  var bk = bookmarks[num];

  if (bk)
    bk.restore();
}
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <title>test bookmark</title>
        <script type='text/javascript' src='libs/bookmarks.js'></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <input type = "text" id = "txt_id" />
        <input type = "button" value = "create bk" onclick = "createBookmark();" />
        <input type = "button" value = "restore bk 0" onclick = "restoreBookmarkNumber(0);" />
    </body>
</html>
```

Updated to use `childNodes` instead of `children` in `Bookmark`, which doesn't lose the spacing:

```js
function Bookmark(of_elem, name)
{
  this.name = name;
  this.of_elem = of_elem;    
  this.elems = new Array();

  for (var i = 0; i < of_elem.childNodes.length; i++)
    this.elems.push(of_elem.childNodes[i].cloneNode(true));

  return this;
};

Bookmark.prototype.restore = function ()
{
  while (this.of_elem.hasChildNodes())
    this.of_elem.removeChild(this.of_elem.lastChild);

  for (var i = 0; i < this.elems.length; i++)
    this.of_elem.appendChild(this.elems[i].cloneNode(true));
};

var bookmarks = new Array();

function createBookmark()
{
  var name = prompt("Enter bookmark name", "Bookmark " + bookmarks.length);
  var bk = new Bookmark(document.body, name);
  bookmarks.push(bk);
}

function restoreBookmarkNumber(num)
{
  var bk = bookmarks[num];

  if (bk)
    bk.restore();
}
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <title>test bookmark</title>
        <script type='text/javascript' src='libs/bookmarks.js'></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <input type = "text" id = "txt_id" />
        <input type = "button" value = "create bk" onclick = "createBookmark();" />
        <input type = "button" value = "restore bk 0" onclick = "restoreBookmarkNumber(0);" />
    </body>
</html>
```